# Sum of column plus blank cells in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: excel-formula, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to take the sum of the numbers in a column plus the number of blank cells in open office. I named my column `example` and tried the formula

```
=Sum(example) + countblank(example)
```

but that counts all of the blank cells in rows below my data.  How can I do this in a way such that I can add more rows to my data and have the formula still be correct?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make the bottom row in Example a footer row.

E.g. In the example below, Example covers cells A1:A10, with A1:A9 containing the data, and A:10 containing text such as "". You can than simply insert rows above , and the range of Example will automatically expand.

```
     A
--+----
 1|  32
 2|  16
 3|  
 4|   9
 5|  12
 6|   8
 7|  
 8|  10
 9|  12
10|  <END>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a possibility to use a formula to count the number of blanks in the range, up until the last non-blank value:

```
=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(Example;0;0;MAX(IF(ISBLANK(Example);0;ROW(Example)))))
```

This is an array formula, so you'll need to select the Array checkbox in the Formula Wizard in Open Office (or press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER if using Excel).

It works by breaking the problem down into two parts:

1. This snippet calculates which the highest row within Example that contains a non-blank value:

   MAX(IF(ISBLANK(Example);0;ROW(Example)
2. The OFFSET function reduces the size of Example to match the position of the last non-blank cell:

   (OFFSET(Example;0;0; [Number of rows to be considered]))

We now have the range of values that need to be processed, to which we apply the COUNTBLANKS formula.